# Hammering to form a magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields

[image]

Take the following diagram. I understand that if we hammered the material in a magnetic field, the molecular vibration caused by the shock of the hammer would cause domains to realign, creating a magnet. But how is it we can demagnetize the same material by hammering it again? How would we need to orient the material in the above setup so that when we hit it, it will become demagnetized?

Say I turned the magnetic material by 90 degrees, If I were to hammer it again, couldn't it cause the material to form a magnet but in the long way, why does it demagnetize the material?

I don't understand why the magnet wouldn't have poles oriented in this direction when struck by the hammer again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the magnet has some internal energy E. If you hammer it, giving it some energy, the internal magnetic moments will spin around until they dissipate the excess energy, ending up in some stable state at a given E.

We know an exact solution for a ferromagnet with the lowest energy: where all of the domains are aligned.

But it likely won't fall into that stablest state. There are many other meta-stable states, with many counter-oriented domains, and it is much likelier to fall into one of these states, depending on the size of the magnet (nanomagnets tend to have fewer domains). This would be a "demagnetized" magnet.

In the presence of an external magnetic field, an additional energy gradient is added that tends to push the atoms into a ferromagnetic alignment. For a strong enough field, this will happen reliably, and it will become "magnetized" when you hammer it in the presence of a field.

(i.e., you would have to take it out of the field and hammer it for it to become demagnetized)